# Exposing simple application in gcloud with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I have a simple app which I am following from a basic tutorial :

https://medium.com/@bhargavshah2011/hello-world-on-kubernetes-cluster-6bec6f4b1bfd

1. I create a cluster **hello-world2-cluster**

[image]

2. I "connect" to the cluster using :

   **gcloud container clusters get-credentials hello-world2-cluster --zone us-central1-c --project strange-vortex-286312**
3. I perform a git clone of the "hellow world" project, which is basically some kind of snake game :

   **$ git clone https://github.com/skynet86/hello-world-k8s.git**

   **$ cd hello-world-k8s/**

Next I run "create" on the YAML:

```
kubectl create -f hello-world.yaml
```

Deplyments and services are created as expected :

[image]

*Fine! ALl good!*

*But.... now what????*

What do I do now?

I want to access this app from the outside world. Where is the URL where I can access the application?

How can I get my friend Bob in Timbuktu to call some kind of URL (no need for DNS) to access my application?

I know the answer has something to do with LoadBalancer nodes and Ingress, but there seems to be no proper documentation out there on how to do this for a simple hello world app.

Comment: Well if are your service as NodePort and using the image you sent like reference, you application should be accessible in `machine-ip:30081`. NodePort service opens a port that is accessible from outside of the cluster.

Comment: I don't know how GKE works exactly but it should depend on your cluster configuration. As you can see a service called "hello-world" has been created and it has an internal IP. It means it is accessible only from INSIDE the cluster. 
By default you have to create a service of type "LoadBalancer" so it will have an external IP. But as you are on GKE, maybe your cluster already has an external IP and you could try to access it by "cluster-ip:30081" but I highly doubt it will work. I'm used to Azure Kubernetes Service and it comes with a default "global" LoadBalancer.

Comment: so what would my URL be? machine-ip:30081, is it google.cloud.hello-world.com ? I am so thoroughly confused. I just need to link to my app from the outside world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**GKE hello-world with `Ingress` Official Example**: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress

The ingress controller is built-in in GKE, you just need a `kind: Ingress` object that points to your `Service`. Addressing your question:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-world
          servicePort: 80
```

Once deployed, query `kubectl get ingress hello-ingress -oyaml` to find out the resulting load-balancer's IP in the `status:` field.

Comment: I'm even more confused now. I have everything setup in my gcloud. I just want some URL where I can access it. So I need to create a GKE Ingress controller?

Comment: Ingress object. I edited my answer to link the exact sample to follow.

Comment: Also added ingress sample. It's really close the example I refer, just stick to that https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress

Comment: I tried that, and I got status --> loadBalancer --> ingress --> ip --> 34.102.214.148. I tried entering that IP in my browser but I got a 404 error :(   (http://34.102.214.148)

Comment: `curl http://34.102.214.148/` shows me `502 Server Error`. If you don't see this error in pod logs, it must be a port misconfig. Things to check: 1. app server listens on `0.0.0.0` and your  selected port, 2. pod port is exposed in deployment yaml 3. service port points to correct pod port

Comment: I suggest trying the https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress from scratch as it eliminates all these misconfigurations

Comment: hmmm it seems to work for me today! Alright thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to set up a DNS and/or an ingress, you can simply do it with what you already have using the **node external ip**.

It seems that you already have the deployement and the `NodePort` service is mapped to port `30081`.

So, below are the remaining steps to make it work with what you have :

1. Get your node IP :

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

2. Now that you have your node external IP, you need to allow tcp traffic to this port

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-tcp-30081 --allow tcp:30081
```

3. That's it ! You can just tell you're friend Bob that the service should be accessible at *node-ip:30081*

You can have a look at [this page](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps) to see the other possibilities depending on your service type.

Also, when you use a `NodePort` the port is mapped to all the nodes of your cluster, so you can use any IP. No need to look for the node where your replicas is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Ingress or anything. You can expose your deployment as LoadBalancer then using external IP your friend bob can access application. So to use

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-world-deployment --name=hello-world-deployment --type=LoadBalancer --port 80 --target-port 80
```

This will take around 1 minute to assign an external IP address to the service.

to get external IP use

```
kubectl get services
```

Get the `External IP address` in-front of your service and open your browser and enter the `IP address that you copied`.

Done !! This is the easiest and simplest way to get start with !!

Answer (score 1):

You can expose your Kubernetes services to the internet with an `Ingress`.

GKE allows you to use different kinds of `Ingress` (`nginx` based, and so on) but, by default, it will expose your service through the [Cloud Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing) service.

As indicated by @MaxLobur, you can configure this default `Ingress` applying a configuration file similar to this:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: hello-world
    servicePort: 80
```

Or, equivalently, if you want to prepare your `Ingress` for various backend services and configure it based on rules:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
          backend:
            serviceName: hello-world
            servicePort: 80
```

This `Ingress` will be assigned an external IP address.

You can find which with the following command:

```sh
kubectl get ingress hello-world-ingress
```

This command will output something similar to the following:

```
NAME                  HOSTS     ADDRESS         PORTS     AGE
hello-world-ingress   *         203.0.113.12    80        2m
```

But, if you give this IP address to your friend Bob in Timbuktu, he will call you back soon telling you that he cannot access the application...

Now seriously: this external IP address assigned by GCP is temporary, an ephemeral one subject to change.

If you need a deterministic, fixed IP address for your application, you need to configure a static IP for your `Ingress`.

This will also allow you to configure, if necessary, a DNS record and SSL certificates for your application.

In GCP, the first step in this process is [reserving a static IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address). You can configure it in the GCP console, or by issuing the following `gcloud` command:

```sh
gcloud compute addresses create hello-world-static-ip --global
```

This IP should be later assigned to your `Ingress` by modifying its configuration file:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "hello-world-static-ip"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: hello-world
    servicePort: 80
```

This static IP approach only adds value because as long as it is associated with a Google Cloud network resource, you will not be charged for it.

All this process is documented in this [GCP documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer).